# Add period or punctuation to end of records in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

I've got a column in my database with descriptions. When the data was entered some of the descriptions are missing a period at the end and I would like to update the rows and add them if they don't exist.

Is the best approach to use the `REGEXP` function or is there a better way?

**EDIT :**
This ended up being more complex than I had originally thought so I wanted to share this process for anyone else that may find it useful.

1. The first complication was that I had records with whitespace and other characters at the end of some strings, which I took care of like this.

   ```
   UPDATE table_name SET col_name = REPLACE(TRIM(TRAILING ' ' FROM col_name), 
                                            TRIM(TRAILING '\r' FROM col_name), 
                                            TRIM(TRAILING '\n' FROM col_name))
   ```
2. The second issue was excluding several other punctuation marks when adding the period. So here is the final query.

   ```
   UPDATE table_name
   SET col_name = CONCAT(col_name,'.')
   WHERE RIGHT(col_name,1) <> '.'
   AND RIGHT(col_name,1) <> '!'
   AND RIGHT(col_name,1) <> '?'
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `right` function https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_right

```
mysql> SELECT RIGHT('foobarbar', 1);
+-----------------------+
| RIGHT('foobarbar', 1) |
+-----------------------+
| r                     |
+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT RIGHT('foobarbar.', 1);
+------------------------+
| RIGHT('foobarbar.', 1) |
+------------------------+
| .                      |
+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So may be you can do as

```
update table_name
set col_name = concat(col_name,'.')
where right(col_name,1) <> '.'
```

Comment: `RIGHT(...,1)` is probably faster than `LIKE '%.'`, so I prefer this answer.

Comment: Please see my comment to Gordon above. Unfortunately this query has the same problem, there are also records returned which already have a period and no whitespace. It's very odd.

Comment: Can you provide some example data of ending punctuations other than period which you do not want to update ?

Comment: Well for example....`?`,`!`, and `"` but I can work that out. Found out the rows that were returning had a carriage return. I am going to accept your answer because it is ever so slightly faster than the one above and less complex than the one below. Thanks Abhik.

Comment: @RickJames . . . They are probably about the same.  However, `LEFT(. . . , 1)` is slower than `LIKE '.%'`, because the latter can use indexes.

Answer (score 4):

Just use `update` and `like`:

```
update table t
    set col = concat(col, '.')
    where col not like '%.';
```

EDIT:

For multiple types of punctuation, you could use a regular expression, but I would just do:

```
update table t
    set col = concat(col, '.')
    where right(col, 1) not in ('.', ';', '!', '?', . . .);
```

Comment: Just as a test, I tried this as a select statement. I quickly found out the problem is more complex than I thought because the strings could end in other punctuation in which case I don't want to add a period but is easy to deal with. Some also had whitespace or a line break which obviously requires a different solution. This of course is beyond the scope of my question, but I also found multiple rows using this approach that did in fact already have a period and no whitespace/line break. I don't understand why unless there is a hidden character?

Comment: Discovered that the culprit was a carriage return `\r`.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table
SET description=IF(RIGHT(description,1)<>'.', description, CONCAT(description, '.'));
```

Basically, this just updates every value in the description field; if it ends in a period, it just inserts the same value (ie. doesn't change anything). If it doesn't end in a period, it concatenates one onto the end.

Comment: Wrong -- don't check for `= ''`, check for `!= '.'`

Answer (score 0):

```
REGEXP '[.!?][[:space:]]*$'
```

That is 'true' for trailing punctuation *optionally* followed by zero or more whitespace characters, including space, CR, and LF.

And this is *probably* more efficient than any other technique because it is looking at each row only once (no ANDs or ORs).  (Yes, REGEXP is generally slower than LIKE.  But this is a case where one REGEXP is doing the work of several LIKEs/RIGHTs/etc.)

Sure, you might want to pre-TRIM the data.  That cuts my 'answer' down to

```
WHERE col_name NOT REGEXP '[.!?]$'
```